# Writing a Simple jQuery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to get a simple jQuery AJAX script to work, but I am having no luck.  This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#doAjax').click(function(){
    alert('Button was clicked');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/test5/process.php",
      data: {test: '1'},
      contentType: "text",
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data){
        alert("Successful POST.  Data returned is " + data);
      } // end success: function(data){
    });// end $.ajax({
  }); // end $('#doAjax').click(function(){
}); // end $(document).ready(function(){
```

On my reply URL (localhost/test5/process.php), here is my reply code:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $reqkey => $reqval)
  {
  echo "<br />REQUEST item $reqkey has a value of $reqval<br />";
  }
echo "END RETURN STRING";
```

I see the alert that the button was pressed, but I get no alert for a successful POST, nor do I receive any data.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: well is the error handler triggered? `error : function(e){console.log(e); }`

Comment: Should also be using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` in your PHP script.

Comment: Also your `dataType` is not text, it's html

Comment: Look at the console in firebird or Chrome Devtools.

Comment: $_REQUEST handles both $_POST and $_GET requests, so that shouldn't matter.  Switching datatype to html makes no difference.  I added the error: function(e){console.log(e)} line under my success line, opened my chrome console and clicked the button.  Nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a variable of a constant, dont use quotes. Also multiple things can be sent from one ajax request. Just use a comma to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/test5/process.php",
        data: {
            test: '1',
            test2: '2'
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Successful POST.  Data returned is " + data);
        }
    });
```

and your php:

```
<?php
foreach($_REQUEST as $reqkey => $reqval)
{
    echo "<br />REQUEST item $reqkey has a value of $reqval<br />";
}
?>
```